# Did Bruno Ganz know Greek language?

Tags: dialogue, eternity-and-a-day

[Bruno Ganz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_Ganz) was a Swiss actor who acted in many German and English movies. He also acted in the Greek movie [Eternity and a Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_and_a_Day) as the main actor.

I'm wondering if he learned a new language just to act in this movie.

Did he learn/know Greek or did he just say the dialogue without understanding the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the IMDb [Trivia Page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0156794/trivia?item=tr1700832) for the movie [Eternity and a Day](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0156794/)

> Bruno Ganz delivered his lines in German and was dubbed into Greek.

The actor who dubbed his lines is [Petros Fyssoun.](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0299561/?ref_=tt_cl_t10)